# Hardware for suspending wood beams from a wall

Tags: hardware

I have an idea for some external decor feature on my home. In order to execute on it, I need a special kind of fastening hardware that I couldn’t begin to guess the name of.

The closest thing I’ve found is a hanger bolt or a stand-off screw, but what I would really like is something that has built in washers or “platforms” as pictured.

The hanger bolt has neither and all the stand off pins or screws I’ve found don’t have the kind of depth I would need to fasten those beams down (*I’m looking for about 3/4” worth of depth*).

I’ve illustrated the needed hardware in this image:

[image]

Comment: I think you have to build the standoff... it can be as simple as a thick dowel with the right sized hole in the middle. Or it can be complicated with washers and a thinner sleeve. (Plus the hanger bolt, of course...)

Comment: I am curious as to how this will be used, functional and or aesthetic?

Comment: It will be purely for aesthetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a cedar hand rail and came up with a stand off to set it off of the posts by a couple of inches.

I used a carriage bolt but you could do it with a lag bolt or machine bolt.

Lag into house, washer, sleeve, washer, lumber with recessed/counter sink hole, washer, lag head.

[image]

Edit: Since people are interested, here is another photo.

[image]

Comment: Thumbs up in part for the elegance. I bet it'll age really nicely.

Comment: Thanks. I routed coves on both sides for thumb and fingers. After i installed it  i stepped back and said out load for all to hear, which was only me,  **Genius**.

Comment: I like the copper tie-in with the post cap too.

Comment: Nice. _Very_ nice. Gives me ideas for replacing the "quickie" hand rail I put up on our front steps (with cheapie non-treated lumber) a couple of years ago. We knew it would need to be replace, this will look _nice_... Looks like you just used some copper plumbing pipe. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is beautiful. I love the color too. How did you do the sleeve?

Comment: @FreeMan Yup, 3/4" copper pipe as a sleeve, just sandwiched between two black washers.  I could have taken the time to burnish it or to treat it but i though i would let the natural patina take its coarse. I wanted cedar posts but she did not want to spring for them.